# Invoking lambda from API gateway test, but hitting the endpoint does not invoke the lambda. 500 returned

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an api gateway that triggers a lambda method. I'm trying to hit the endpoint and I get a 500 returned, InternalServerErrorException. However, the lambda was never invoked.

When logging into the aws console, I run the test interface in the api gateway. I get a 502, InternalServerErrorException. Logs say the lambda timed out after 3 seconds. Viewing cloudwatch it's clear the lambda was invoked this time.

I can't find any documentation on why I would be getting a 500 InternalServerErrorException when hitting the endpoint and it would not invoke the lambda, but I would be able to invoke it with the test button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been struggling for a bit with this one. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you have to allow API Gateway to invoke the Lambda function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-permissions. And as it times out after 3 seconds, you probably need to increase the timeout. Or fix the function. :)

Comment: So if my API Gateway did not have permissions to invoke the function, I would be able to invoke it from the test interface? That seems strange.

Comment: Nope, there is another explanation about 5xx errors a bit further down the page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#services-apigateway-errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your API is working properly with the test button, but, you are receiving this error, looks like your API is not deployed.

To deploy your API go to Actions > Deploy API:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, finally I got my API working. Do you have any background information on how this is even possible? I did have a beta stage before. I didn't see any changes.

The whole setup is created using CDK, so I wouldn't expect this to be missing. Any pointers are helpful!